# Element could not be scrolled into view error

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver

I have been working on a simple recipe app in django and want to be able to sort the recipes by country of origin. I am trying to get the hang of Test Driven Development, so I am using Selenium.

Unfortunately, I get this error. I'm confused because there should only be one recipe in the database, and yet a call for a second recipe is made when the recipe doesn't exist. When I run python manage.py runserver, I can interact with the recipe card exactly the way I would imagine, but I get an error when trying to test it.

How should I fix this error?

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element `'<a class="recipe-card" href="/recipes/2/">'` could not be scrolled into view

(edit) I have tried adding a second recipe to test with, but am then told that /recipes/3/ could not be scrolled into view.

The Selenium test code

```
class RecipesTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = WebDriver()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.continent = Continent.objects.create(name='test_continent')
        self.country_1 = Country.objects.create(name='test country 1', 
            continent = self.continent)
        self.country_2 = Country.objects.create(name='test country 2', 
            continent = self.continent)
        self.recipe_1 = Recipe.objects.create(name='test recipe 1', 
            country = self.country_1)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_recipes(self):
        self.browser.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, 
            '/countries/1/'))
        recipe = self.browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, 
            value="recipe-card")
        recipe.click()
```

The html file recipe_list.html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for recipe in recipes %}
<a href="{% url 'recipes:recipe_detail' recipe.id %}" class="recipe-card">
    <div>
        <h1>{{recipe.name}}</h1>
    </div>
</a>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
def recipe_list(request, pk):
    recipes = list(Recipe.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'countries/recipe_list.html', {
        'recipes': recipes,
    })
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.country_list, name='country_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.recipe_list, name='recipe_list'),
]
```

Comment: the click method will attempt to scroll the item into view if needed.  For some reason it's having trouble with that.  What does your 'recipe-card' css style look like?  Also, are you doing any "lazy-loading"?

Comment: So far I am still just trying to get things to work, so I haven't done any styling. I am not doing any lazy-loading. I wouldn't think it would need to be scrolled in as the link is the only thing on the page. I don't have anything in core/base.html. I just don't know why when I run the test it gives me an error that recipe 2 can't be found when I have never made a recipe 2.

Comment: It found one... your locator is only specifying a class/style of "recipe-card", which could be many different elements.  Better to target an ID specific to each one...  I'm starting to suspect that it is writing that element, but it is empty... (you can't see it, and Selenium can't find it's size/location, so it fails to scroll)  Check size of your recipes array and/or check the DOM at the time this selector runs... right-click in the browser, and choose "inspect".

Comment: I was able to figure it out. There were two problems going on. The first is that I had the recipe creation as part of the setUp function which meant that I had duplicate recipes when I went to search for them. The other issue is that I had my div inside of my a tag. When I moved the div to the outside, I was then able to access the recipe card I was looking for.